# Show sliding animation when a <div> shows up in ReactJS-render()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, css

Say this is how 2 divs show and hide in my React application. How can I add animation to the 2 divs when they show up?

```
render() {
   return (
       {this.state.showDiv1 ?
           <div className="div1">
              ...
           </div>
           :
           <div className="div2">
              ...
           </div>
        }
   )
}
```

Comment: You can simply add class to the divs and write up your animation properties on that class in CSS, if that's what you meant.

Comment: @Rikin This is want I wanted. I am not familiar with CSS animation so this question may look silly. Here is a solution I found: https://codeburst.io/animating-dynamically-created-elements-pure-css-c864fdb6e366

Comment: Yep, so did you found solution, or you still need help on how to render that behavior here in React code? @lonelyloner

Comment: @Rikin no. Thank you!